# Как в Android Studio сделать сборку с параметрами?

Tags: android-studio

Требуется уже готовый проект отдать заказчику, но так, чтобы он мог в понятном для "юзера" месте написать нужные значения для кода. Как это сделать? Слышал про build.xml, это то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Нет.** Build.xml - XML-файл структуры проекта, чтобы его смог собрать [Ant](http://ant.apache.org). Для задания для Java-кода значений инициализации существуют Propetries-файлы.